# Faulty DOM rendering every refresh

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, render

This is getting kinda weird.

I am designing a website and every time I refresh my site (localhost) in safari, google chrome, the elements move someplace else and when refresh back after a few times, it corrects and after refreshing again, the rendering is faulty again.

Do you guys have any idea?

One thing I notice is that when it renders faulty, the way it display the screen is not instant instead it starts on the upperleft, folding to the lower right like a curtain.

It works good in opera, firefox, IE.

Thanks!

EDIT:

I tried to ask my friend to load it in his computer and it looks like it is doing well on his side. It looks like a problem on my Computer. I'll go try the codes out myself in another computer and re-edit my post when I see the results. Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: `Do you guys have any idea?` Put it on some hosting, give us a link. I do not think that just html code will be enough to see. And validate your page here http://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does any of the html elements don't have a display property or width specified? Post the html markup and css for better understanding your problem.